# Load External JavaScript File

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load an external javascript file from within javascript but I cannot seem to get it to work. Am I doing something wrong?

[sample file](http://www.sfu.ca/~jca41/stuph/loadJs.html) of my work

```
function loadJs() {
var fileref=document.createElement('script')
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
fileref.setAttribute("src", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js")
document.body.appendChild(fileref); }
```

Comment: Why do you want to load jquery dynamically? Perhaps there is a better solution.

Comment: It is part of a project I am working on. Realistically, I would just load it in HTML using <script> :)

Comment: Are you sure document.body exists when this runs? If this runs from the head, document.body won't exist yet.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you are trying to access the jQuery API before it is fully loaded. You can add a callback parameter to the loadJs function like this:

```
function loadJs(src, callback) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
    s.onload = function() {
        //callback if existent.
        if (typeof callback == "function") callback();
        callback = null;
    }
    s.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (s.readyState == 4 || s.readyState == "complete") {
            if (typeof callback == "function") callback();
            callback = null; // Wipe callback, to prevent multiple calls.
        }
    }
    s.src = src;
}

loadJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js', function() {
    $('body').append('<p>It works!</p>');
});
```

Tested in chrome, FF, ie8. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Umwbx/2/

Comment: @David I have updated your answer by adding a correct implementation of `onreadystatechange`.

Comment: This script helped me so solve $.getScript problems in android 4.0.* and no more "unknown chromium error 6"

Answer (score 0):

Use code similar to this:

```
function loadJs() {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    var c = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';
    c.parentNode.insertBefore(s, c);
}
```

Comment: I tried your above code in Chrome and it did not seem to be working. When I mouse over the word 'hello', the background colour does not change.

Comment: It is working, if you inspect the code in Chrome Developer Tools / Firebug you will see the script tag added. The background color is not changing because you are calling the jquery code before jquery is even loaded.