# Why do the pages blink/flicker after transitions in my jQuery Mobile PhoneGap app on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a jQuery Mobile app that I've converted to an iOS app using PhoneGap. I'm using version 1.1.0 of jQM.

I'm using "fade" transitions between pages (as I read they were less demanding).

When initially running the PhoneGap version of the app in the iPhone Simulator I was getting a flicker/flash after every page transition - as if the page was being displayed, cleared and then redisplay - all with a fraction of a second. Some thing happened when I ran it on the device.

I applied the advice in Sarah-Jane's answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953753/flickering-when-navigating-between-pages).

This fixed the problem in the simulator, but not on the actual device.

Has anyone experienced this problem, and found a solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This guy solved the problem - it worked for me:

http://outof.me/fixing-flickers-jumps-of-jquery-mobile-transitions-in-phonegap-apps/

CSS:

```
body {
    /* Setting body margins to 0 to have proper positioning of #container div */
    margin: 0;
}

/* #container div with absolute position and 100% width and height so it takes up whole window */
#container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).one("mobileinit", function () {

    // Setting #container div as a jqm pageContainer
    $.mobile.pageContainer = $('#container');

    // Setting default page transition to slide
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'slide';

});
```

And wrap all your jQM pages in a single `<div id="container">`

Comment: This worked flawlessly to solve my "white page" problems too.

Comment: Sorry but this is not working. What version of PhoneGap, jQuery and jQuery mobile are you using and in what iOS?

Comment: Whichever versions that were released at the time of writing. Sorry, I don't remember.

Answer (score 1):

Fade transition blinks mostly you should change it to slide or some other transition mode.

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't resolve it - I just get a different flicker.

Comment: I had similar problem in my app then i did steps that fixed the issue 1) Changed all transition to slide 2) checked all function calls that render the pages , may be there is any duplicate calls (i render all my pages dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

That might help

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

Answer (score -1):

use following code

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 

    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "none"
    $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
    $.mobile.useFastClick = true; 
    $.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = true;

});
```