# jQuery Mobile flickering screen during transitions

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, flicker

I am testing a mobile web application built in jQuery Mobile 1.1.0. I am testing the website application using my Galaxy Nexus running on android 4.0.
There is a nasty flicker on the CSS swipe transition and i have looked around for fixes and found this:

```
.ui-page {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

However, when i use this fix, the index page which has a listview does not display. Please help me. What could be the problem?

Comment: Had a similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401938/jquery-mobile-listview-phantom-not-refreshed-in-android-4

Comment: See my answer to this question, I got it working: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12749862/561545

Comment: In case you need only transitions from jQM it`s better to use https://github.com/PixelsCommander/Mobile-Transitions - no blinks, better perfomance, easier to use.

Answer (score 4):

The only real way to prevent the "flickering" is to disable the jQuery Mobile page transitions altogether. In the  of your document, place this code:

```
// load your custom jQuery Mobile Defaults
<script type="text/javascript" src="mobile/js/mobile-site-custom-jqm-defaults.js"></script>

// load jQuery Mobile
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

// load your scripts.js (your javascript & functions, etc.)
<script type="text/javascript" src="mobile/js/script.js"></script>
```

To disable transitions, inside of the mobile-site-custom-jqm-defaults.js file, place this code:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.extend(  $.mobile , {
   defaultPageTransition: 'none'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I found on network this solution:

`if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Android") != -1) {
   $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
   $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
}`

I tested it on Android app written with use of cordova 2.2.0, jquery 1.8.2 and jquery mobile 1.2.0. And I must say it works. I hope the jquery mobile dev team will solve transitions flickering but now the only way is to turn them all off. I want to add that I checked all css tricked from first 30 google searches on this topic.

Comment: This bug has been around as long as JQueryMobile and is likely the most famous.  Don't count on it being fixed any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me too (especially in iOS). Then I used

```
<a href="index.php" data-transition="none">Index</a>
```

It worked for me.
[Page transition](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html)