# How do I Internally Linked Pages? (HTML)

Tags: android, html

So I am making a Web based app.
I have all of the code down, but it flashes whenever it switches pages.
I thought, how about I make all of my pages internal? 
Here is some basic code I make of how I think you do Internal Pages, and it won't work.
What is wrong?

http://pastebin.com/kSCyKKgx

EDIT: This is for an Android App!

Comment: What do you mean by "making pages internal"?

Comment: All the code is in one HTML File and stuff links to parts of it.

Comment: What makes your links not internal then?

Comment: I posted this to see what is wrong. In my real app I have several different HTML pages.

Answer (score 3):

The "flash" you see is the browser clearing up the rendering before loading and rendering the new page. This is normal.

If you want to avoid these, you need to invest time into learning how to use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) effectively - this essentially is you getting data from the server in JavaScript and rendering in client side, so the browser doesn't ever load a new page (avoid the "flash").

There is lots to thing about though when implementing the above (things like browser history, making pages linkable and more).

Comment: Well my freind and I are making the same type of app, and his pages are linked internally, and it works a lot better.

Comment: @Stevenator21 - What do you mean by "linked internally"?

Answer (score 0):

That "FLICKERING" you are seeing, could be that you are on a Android 2.x device, maybe?

If so, you can try adding this to any CSS that loads after the main jquery mobile ones in your HEAD section.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-page {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
```

Comment: there is no mention of "Android"

Comment: It is on Android though, and @Anthony Trimble , what would have this CSS Class?

Comment: I had that same problem with jQuery mobile. See this answer....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029427/jquery-mobile-flickering-screen-during-transitions.

Comment: PS I know there is no mention of Android, I was using my powers of deduction...and was right...ps thanks for that vote down!

Comment: I didn't vote you down! I would vote up but this is my 1st Question. What in the HTML would have this CSS Class?

Comment: @Stevenator21 you can add this to your HEAD tag below the loading the jquery mobile CSS style sheets to help with the flicker. OR, make your links likes this <a href="index.php" data-transition="none">Index</a>

Comment: @Stevenator21 Sorry I did not think you voted it down :)

Comment: Okay, thx! Do you know what is wrong with my code though?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your code. It is an android bug and a jquery thing. Was I correct, are you using Android 2.x.x to test your app?

Comment: I actualy currently don't have an Android Device currently, it is at my freind's house, although I can have him test it. It does not work on my laptop though. THere is still a flash.

Comment: In a few of your links you are calling two transitions, "<a href="#1" ...data-transition="fade"...data-transition="pop"..." I would not do that. Try data-transition="none" and see if that gets rid of the flicker. But I would also test on a mobile device. Emulators and web Browsers can only do so much to replicate the mobile environment.

Comment: Okay, I will get it onto an Android device in the next 10 min. The problem is that code doesn't switch pages :)

Comment: Drop the rel-external attribute. Those links are not external, you are on the same page.

Comment: Ohhhhh! BTW: My freind tested it on the Galaxy Note 2 and there is still as much flash.