# JQuery-Mobile Page transitions - flickering (separate pages)

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, web-applications, cordova

I spend the day figuring out how to fix the flickering between page transitions in JQuery-Mobile 1.3.1.

I found that

```
.ui-page { -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }
```

or setting the `data-transition` to `none`

or removing `meta.attr( "content", disabledZoom );` and `meta.attr( "content", enabledZoom );` from JQM file

helped.

**But apparently that is only working if the webapp is just one "multi-page".**

**I am using 4 separate pages.**

In iOS (mobile Safari) and on PC (Browser: Chrome) I don't have any transition flickering.
But as soon as I add the App to to the Homescreen it flickers again.

Here I read that there is no possibility in avoiding page flickering for (PhoneGap/Homescreenapp) if there are separate HTML files in use: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/phonegap/tqdv3tYIj_o/qfft32VbLg8J

**Is there no solution for this?**

Comment: Can you please show the code you have tried...as mentioned in the question those options usually help to get rid of jquery mobile flickering page transitions.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q5hrx/ this is my code, I recoded it, because I can't show my exact code for legal reasons. It's just the content. But the structure is the same. On MobileSafari/homescreen-app/phonegap-app this site will flicker/blink after navigating

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Mobile flickering screen during transitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029427/jquery-mobile-flickering-screen-during-transitions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Work-around Solution**

So, these are the things I tried:

- `data-transition="none"` / `$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';`
- `.ui-page { backface-visibility: hidden;
             -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Chrome and Safari */
             -moz-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Firefox */ }`
- delete `meta.attr( "content", disabledZoom );` & `meta.attr( "content", enabledZoom );` in jquery.mobile.js
- `-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);`
- `data-position="fixed"` headers/footers
- deactivating user scale in meta tags

It did not work for "Homescreen-App"/"PhoneGap-App"
I also applied `body{ background-color: black !important }` to make the blink appear more subtile , which worked but was still ugly.

**So I found a work-around solution: `jQuery 1.1.0 RC2` and `jQuery 1.7.1`: no flickering when data-transition is set to none.**

Answer (score 7):

Nothing answered so far worked for me.
I ended up binding a function to all links or elements which cause a page change.
In the function, i trigger the page change but explicitely tell it 'none' for the transition.

Here is an example:

Javscript (jQuery)

```
$('.item-navbar-people').on('tap', function (e) {
  $.mobile.changePage("#page-people", { transition: "none" });
});
```

Markup

```
<div data-role="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="item-navbar-people ui-btn-active">People</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your tip. Nothing else but your suggestion solved the problem on my end.

Comment: This worked great for me. I had set transition: none globally anyway, but for some reason, only when I concatenated all my scripts with grunt, the active page was flickering on one specific changePage call. Brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue.

Disabling/Enabling `zoom` BEFORE each page transition will resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for answering. What exactly do you mean? I already disabled zoom via meta tags:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`

Answer (score 0):

I figure out it, changing the scale of viewport meta tag.

Let's me clarify...
In my tests I saw that when I apply some zoom in page on mobile devices, the transition works perfectly. So, just change the initial-scale in your viewport meta tag to something higher than 1.0, something like 1.01 for example. That's it!

Example:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.01">
```

Answer (score -1):

I spent weeks trying all suggested solutions in the Internet, what works for jquery.mobile-1.3.2 , Android 4.1.2, phonegap 2.9.0 is to delete these lines in jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js file

```
meta.attr( “content”, disabledZoom );  // just put // before the line



meta.attr( “content”, enabledZoom ); // just put // before the line
```

This will eliminate double flicks, also

set data-transition between pages to none

```
data-transition="none"
```

(The second fix is temporally until you can find a solution to get ride of remaining white page during transition)

Using this solution, no need to remove data-position="fixed" from header or footer which is one of helping solutions, but affecting interface design.

source: comments on http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2011/07/14/eliminating-annoying-flicker-transitions-with.html

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and something that sped things up and eliminated the flickering effect was implementing fastclick.js found here: https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick.

After linking to the .js file,

Add

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        FastClick.attach(document.body);
    });
</script>
```

to the head of your document.

Voila. That helped me, hope it helps you too!